# Box shadow aparecendo da direita para a esquerda

Tags: html, css3

Estou com o seguinte código http://codepen.io/leoamrl/pen/xErdQL que até agora está exatamente como eu quero. Exceto porque eu quero que o efeito hover apareça da direita para a esquerda. Como eu conseguiria faze-lo com box shadow?

Segue como é o layout para terem uma idéia.

[image: Já está igual aqui, só preciso que entre da direita para a esquerda]

Estou quebrando a cabeça mas não consegui nada ainda.

Se tiverem alguma outra solução para isso que não use o box shadow também serve, desde que não use imagens.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma ideia aí pode adaptar:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}
.header{
  float:left;
  background-color: blue;
  height:auto;
  padding:16px;
}

li{
  font: 500 16px Poppins, sans-serif;
 
        width:auto;
        margin-right: 20px;
        height:5px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height:0px;
        background: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, blue 50%);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 205% 100% ;
        background-position:  ;
        transition:all 1s ease;
        list-style-type:none;
        
}
li:hover{
       
        background-position:right;}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">suporte</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas o Diretor de Arte quer da maneira que está no layout.

Comment: @LeoAmaral dei uma alterada, espero que ajude...

Comment: A idéia seria que o shadow aparecesse  somente na metade do texto, não tipo bg, como está aí.

Comment: Como exatamente é o efeito que deseja ? Da direita para esquerda, metade da vertical ? Metade da horizontal ? Metade dos 2 ?

Comment: Da direita para a esquerda. Obtive a resposta exata aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209915/box-shadow-appearing-from-right-to-left

Comment: @LeoAmaral Exata, exata como a visão de um programador deve ser, não está, afinal as cores estão em preto e branco ;) Fiz uma alteração que eu acredito der ficado mais exato que o "exato" ... Abraço